# WMS / imagery shuts down QGIS & kicks computer offline

Tags: wms

please do not mark this as off topic - it is entirley ON topic. Have contacted QGIS/GitHub directly - no response.

I am running QGIS 3.4.9 Madeira, but on loading WMS ortho-imagery (for North Carolina / NC One Map), QGIS shuts down & my internet connection is shut down entirely.  I'm then then blocked from internet access entirely, sometimes through several re-boots.

Additionally, on loading any project, I often get a failure notice that existing / saved streaming imagery in the project ( "failed to load capabilities..." and then no WMS streaming will work.

I'm running Windows 8 / 64bit and running this version since June, but this issue only recently started - has never occurred in any prev. version.

Can't find anything about this issue online or on Stack-Ex. Again, please remove or do not mark as off topic...I have no other source for assistance.

Comment: Contact your Internet Service Provider

Comment: You might rename your QGIS profile, restart QGIS and see if that fixes things.  If not you can rename it back and look elsewhere for problems.  If it does fix things then you can keep it and then rebuild your customizations and connections.  You might save your working WMS connections to an xml file to reload in the Data Source Manager WFM Layers section.

Comment: Already contacted ISP - no help whatsoever.